Extracting data from a UTF-8 file format and importing it into a utf-8 file format in VBA
I would like to extract a Japanese letters data from a UTF-8 file format and copying it into another utf-8 file format.
Expected output: ｶｶｶｶｶｶｶｶｶ字字字字字字字
Actual output: ・ｶ・ｶ・ｶ・ｶ・ｶ・'蟄怜ｭ怜ｭ怜ｭ怜ｭ怜ｭ怜  (garbage data)
Sub ReadTextFileDataInExcel()
    Dim TblNum As String
    TblNum = Worksheets("data").Range("A2").Value
    Dim RowNumber   As Long
    Dim TextFile    As String
    Dim LineData    As String
    Dim stemp() As Collection
    Dim Test As Variant
    
    TextFile = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & TblNum & "\" & "CA003" & "\10_RunScript\20.ExpectResult.sql"
    
    MyDir = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & TblNum & "\" & "CA003" & "\10_RunScript"
        MyFileName = MyDir & "\40.ExpectResult.sql"
      
    RowNumber = 1
     
    Dim newTxt As String
    Open TextFile For Input As #1
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, LineData
            If LineData Like "insert*" Then
                Worksheets("40.ExpectResult_TEMP").Range("A" & RowNumber).Value = LineData
                LineData = Replace(LineData, "_DUMMY", "")
                newTxt = newTxt & vbCr & LineData
                RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
            End If
            WriteIfFile_utf8 MyFileName, Mid(newTxt, 2)
        Loop
    Close #1
    
            
End Sub

Function WriteIfFile_utf8(strPath As Variant, str As Variant)
    Dim objStream As Object
    Dim utfStr As Variant
    Set objStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")

    With objStream
        .Type = 2 'adTypeText
        .Charset = "SHIFT-JIS"
        .Open
        .writetext str
        .savetofile strPath, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing
End Function


"copying it into another utf-8 file format" then why not use utf8 for the output file format?

Already tried it, same output. It gives garbage datas.

This worked for me using the sample text you posted:
Sub ReadWriteUTF8()
    
    Dim inFile As String, outFile As String
    Dim LineData As String, inStream As Object, outStream As Object
    
    inFile = "C:\Temp\inputSample.txt"
    outFile = "C:\Temp\outputSample.txt"
    
    Set inStream = GetUTF8Stream(inFile)
    Set outStream = GetUTF8Stream()
    
    Do While Not inStream.EOS
        LineData = inStream.ReadText(-2) 'adReadLine
        Debug.Print LineData Like "*" & vbCr, LineData
        If LineData Like "insert*" Then
            outStream.WriteText LineData, 1 'adWriteLine
        End If
    Loop
    inStream.Close
    outStream.SaveToFile outFile, 2 'adSaveCreateOverWrite
    outStream.Close
End Sub

'return an ADODB.Stream set up for UTF-8 text
Function GetUTF8Stream(Optional strPath As String = "") As Object
    Set GetUTF8Stream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")
    With GetUTF8Stream
        .Type = 2           'adTypeText
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .LineSeparator = -1 'adCRLF=-1, adCR=13, adLF=10
        .Open
        If Len(strPath) > 0 Then .LoadFromFile strPath
    End With
End Function

